# How to calculate input_dim for a keras sequential model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Keras `Dense` layer needs an `input_dim` or `input_shape` to be specified. What value do I put in there?

My input is a matrix of 1,000,000 rows and only 3 columns. My output is 1,600 classes.

What do I put there?

1. dimensionality of the inputs `(1000000, 1600)`
2. `2` because it's a 2D matrix

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`input_dim` is the number of dimensions of the features, in your case that is just 3. The equivalent notation for `input_shape`, which is an actual dimensional shape, is `(3,)`

Comment: But if the shape is `(3,)`, then the number of dimensions is `1`. `a = numpy.array([1,2,3])` → `a.shape == (3,)`, `a.ndim == 1`

Comment: It would be more accurate to say `input_dim`/`input_shape` is the _shape_ of the features, which is a tuple of dimension sizes. The length of the shape tuple is the number of dimensions. (3,) means one dimension (shape tuple contains only one number) of size 3.

Answer (score 3):

In your case 
lets assume x and y=target variable and are look like as follows after feature engineering

```
x.shape
(1000000, 3)
y.shape
((1000000, 1600)
# as first layer in a sequential model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=x.shape[1])) # Input layer
# now the model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 3)
# and output arrays of shape (*, 32)
...
...
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1],activation='softmax')) # Output layer
```

y.shape[1]= 1600, the number of output which is the number of classes you have, since you are dealing with Classification.

Answer (score 1):

`X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13]`

meaning the `X` parameter having all the rows and 3rd column till 12th column inclusive and 13th column exclusive. 
We will also have a `X0` parameter to be given to the neural network, so total

```
input layers becomes 10+1 = 11.

Dense(input_dim = 11, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')
```