# Can I use input_shape instead of input_dim in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676678/how-to-calculate-input-dim-for-a-keras-sequential-model). I understand that I can use  input_shape=(1,) instead of input_dim=1. But when I run the code I got an error `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`. Do I understand correctly or not?

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(50,
    input_dim=1,
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

Comment: I got the following warnings when I run your code: `UserWarning: The 'input_dim' and 'input_length' arguments in recurrent layers are deprecated. Use 'input_shape' instead.` and `UserWarning: Update your 'LSTM' call to the Keras 2 API: 'LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1))`. I think it'll be better to follow the advice and use `input_shape` instead.

Comment: I mean I use  input_dim=1 is work. But input_shape=(1,) is not work

Comment: So does `input_shape=(None, 1)` work?

Comment: It's work thank you so much.